# Space between graphs

Tags: spacing, graphics, floats

I'm trying to put two separate graphs on the same page. Unfortunately the top graph goes at the top of the page and the second graph goes right at the bottom with a big ugly gap between. Generically I've tried \vspace and a few other options but I just can't get it right. Any thoughts?

```latex
\newpage\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\caption{xx}
\includegraphics[scale=.41]{xx.eps}
\end{figure}

\vspace{-10cm}

\begin{figure}
\caption{vv}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{zz.eps}
\end{figure}
\newpage
```

Comment: Put them in the same figure environment.

Comment: note that the vspace is part of the main document flow so will add negative space at that point but figures are floats that may be inserted elsewhere leaving a large negative space at the original point. (you are saved here by it being after a `\clearpage` so discarded)